# Android Studio: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

out of the blue, I got this error that I can not find a way to fix. Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found. If there are any more files that you guys need to see, feel free to ask me. Thank you!

It's referring me to this file:

Here is my build.gradle(Project OddJob):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tamir.offen.actionbar"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url 'https://dl.bintray.com/spark/maven'
    }
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation  fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'me.spark:submitbutton:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'

// for the bottom nav bar:
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

Here is build.gradle(Module App):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tamir.offen.actionbar"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation  fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1"
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'me.spark:submitbutton:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:3.1.3'

    // for the bottom nav bar:
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Android Studio: Plugin with id `'com.android.application'` not found

- You are missing `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'` in top level project `dependencies`.
- Check Top level project `build.gradle`

> build.gradle(Project OddJob):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

//
//task clean(type: Delete) {
//    delete rootProject.buildDir
//}
```

Comment: Do I just copy past this into the build.gradle(project)?

Comment: I got this error:   Declaring custom 'clean' task when using the standard Gradle lifecycle plugins is not allowed. And also what do you mean by 'Check Top level project build.gradle'

Comment: Just remove clean task part and try again, Updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick replays! I deleted the clean task part and got this error: Cannot read packageName from C:\Users\tamir\Desktop\OddJob\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Try to Android Studio > Build > Clean Project .

Comment: I tried cleaning my project and it didn't help(same error)

Comment: Please update your question with, `AndroidManifest.xml`, Seem this file has some error or wrong package.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

- Add the following code to the top of your build.gradle in your project like this:

  ```
  / Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
    projects/modules.

    buildscript {

       repositories {
        google()
       jcenter()
     }
   dependencies {
  classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
  // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
  // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
    }

   allprojects {
    repositories {
  jcenter()
  google()
  }
   }

   task clean(type: Delete) {
   delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
  ```
- Open gradle-wrapper.properties and add url like this:

  ```
       Wed May 30 16:36:49 IST 2018
       distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
       distributionPath=wrapper/dists
       zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
       zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
       distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip  //add this line in you project.
  ```

it helps you